# PHP File Delete Permission Denied

Tags: php, symfony, unlink

I need to delete files in php and i keep getting this error:
N.B : I noticed that all files are deleted except one that causes the error:

> Warning: unlink(c:/wamp/www/EmploiPublic/app/Resources/sessions/sess_f0g4jsreposgbv6dkt36sud0v6): Permission denied

```
$files = glob('c:/wamp/www/EmploiPublic/app/Resources/sessions/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
   chown($file, 0777);
   chmod($file, 0777);
   if(is_file($file)){
      unlink($file); // delete file
   }
}
```

Comment: You can check permissions with functions like `is_writable()`, but firstly why do you need to delete PHP session files by hand?

Comment: `chown` gets user or uid as the second parameter, is `0777` your user's id?

Answer (score 2):

Your `chown` is not correct.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

The second parameter is die username or userid.